# Binary files sent over socket are corrupted

Tags: sockets, tcp, header, send, recv

I'm doing a code that will transfer files between two computers. I'm using tcp socket for the connection. The thing is I need to attach sort of headers to the file bytes that I'm sending so the receiveer know that what I'm sending is part of a file. Let's say my header is `data`. The string I'll send will be: `data <file bytes>`.

I'm able to send them and the receiver is able to receive them but the file seems corrupted. Though for unformatted text files it works well but for other files it doesn't seem to parse the file efficiently.

```
while(1){
    fp = (char*) malloc (56);
    rc = recv(connfd,fp,55,0);

    if(strcmp(fp,"stop") == 0){
        break;
    }

    fp = fp + 5; //I do this to skip the 'data<space>" header
    wr = write(fd,pf2,rc-5);
    tot = tot + wr;
    printf("Received a total of %d bytes rc = %d \n",tot, rc);
}
```

But I've tried sending the file without the header and I get the file uncorrupted but I need to use those 'data' headers for this particular code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems corrupt?  How is it corrupt?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> fp = fp + 5; //I do this to skip the 'data<space>" header
> ```

But you don't receive the `data<space>` header in every `receive()` call. You have to keep a buffer to which you add all data you receive, until you encounter another `"data<space>"`.

Please note though that separators are generally a bad idea. What if you send a file that has the string `"data<space>"` in it? Your client will assume that after that, a new file will be sent, while in fact you're still receiving the original file.

Try to send some kind of message-length-header, for example an uint32, which occupies four bytes before each file you send. You can then read the first four bytes and then you know how many more bytes you can expect for that file.

Comment: Remember, TCP is a **stream**.  It does not pass "packets".  A `recv()` call may not return the same grouping of data from a correspodning `send()` call.  A single send could appear during multiple incoming reads, multiple sends could appear during a single read, or multiple sends could appear as multiple reads but with different boundaries.

Comment: @BrianWhite thanks for the addendum, but if that was directed at me: you're preaching to the choir. ;-)

Comment: nope.  Just clarifying a bit for the original poster how TCP operates.  A **great** many novices think of TCP as packet-based and then get confused when things often work but not always.

Comment: @BrianWhite I know, the regularity of questions that indicated that inspired me to write this: [Sockets and protocols: exchanging messages. Using bytes.](http://codecaster.nl/blog/2012/08/sockets-and-protocols-exchanging-messages-using-bytes/) In short: one `send()` does not mean one `receive()`, just as you said. :-)

Comment: Here is an answer which uses a message length header to denote the size of the incoming message: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12699292/34329