# TcpClient not receiving full server reply

Tags: c#, tcpclient, memorystream, networkstream

The following method is supposed to send a couple of commands to the server. It is also supposed to return full reply from the server as a string. The problem I have is with the reply section of the code; specifically, I am not getting the FULL reply back. If I add the following line `Console.WriteLine(bytesRead);` before the `memoryStream.Write(buffer,0,bytesRead);` I receive the full reply. Seems like this silly line of code helps "pause" something so that all data is returned. I really do not know what I am doing wrong and I need your help. Thanks

```
    public string Send(List<string> commands)
    {
        try
        {
            // String that will contain full reply from server
            string fullServerReply = string.Empty;

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);

            NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            foreach (string command in commands)
            {
                // Check to see if this NetworkStream is writable
                if (networkStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    // Translate the passed message into UTF8 and store it as a byte array.
                    byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);

                    // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Close everything.
                    networkStream.Close();
                    tcpClient.Close();

                    return "";
                }

                // Check to see if this NetworkStream is readable
                if (networkStream.CanRead)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                        do
                        {
                            int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            if (bytesRead <= 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            //Console.WriteLine(bytesRead); <- BY ADDING THIS CODE I GET THE FULL REPLY

                            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        } while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                        fullServerReply += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()); // THIS STRING DOES NOT CONTAIN FULL REPLY
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Close everything.
                    networkStream.Close();
                    tcpClient.Close();

                    return "";
                }
            }

            // Close everything.
            networkStream.Close();
            tcpClient.Close();

            return fullServerReply.Trim();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            return "";
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yup!  [DataAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is NOT indicator that a complete stream has been received.  It only indicates if some data that hasn't yet been ready available in receive buffer.

When you add console.readline, you give network packets a chance to catch up and get more data in buffer.

Instead you should keep looping until either the network stream is closed, or since it is a tcp stream, whatever the protocol you're using that tells you how big your application packet is to keep reading for.

Comment: Could you point me to an example of how I check if network stream is closed? The protocol that the server uses does not tell me the size of the packet.

Comment: So is the "protocol" basically send request and keep reading everything until socket is closed by the peer?

Comment: @jadrijan I believe the answer in [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652791/tcp-client-server-client-doesnt-always-read?rq=1) uses proper technique, though I say this only after quite cursory examination of it - take this recommendation with a grain of salt (and some pepper) :).

Answer (score 2):

That's kind of how networking works - you cannot assume that you get everything back instantly, or in the same number of reads as there were writes. In your case, adding the write to the console was *just enough* to have the client spool everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to flush all the writes to the stream after the loop:

```
memoryStream.Flush();
memoryStream.Position = 0;
fullServerReply += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()); // THIS STRING DOES NOT CONTAIN FULL REPLY
```