# JSON deserialization works locally but not when from remote server

Tags: c#, json.net, client-server

Weird problem here.

I have two applications.

**Server app**
A Unity3D application which captures the frames from the game, converts to JSON and sends to the connected client.

**Client app**
Connects to server and receives data via TCP. Received data is converted to a string and then deserialized from JSON to an object.

**Server send:**

```
public void Send(byte[] dataToSend)
{
    var message = new MessageData();
    message.Bytes = dataToSend;
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

    var bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
    clientSocket.Send(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length, SocketFlags.None);

}
```

**Client Receive:**

```
    public void StartReceiving(TcpClient client)
    {
        if (!client.Connected) return;

        try
        {
            var stream = client.GetStream();

            if (!stream.DataAvailable) return;

            var buffer = new byte[500000];
            var bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            var json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

            var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageData>(json);

            //raise image received event
            ImageReceivedEventArgs args = new ImageReceivedEventArgs();
            args.Bytes = message.Bytes;
            args.Time = DateTime.Now;
            OnImageReceived(args);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

**MessageData** is just a class with a byte array property called "Bytes".

Now, for some reason, this all works absolutely fine locally and the JSON comes out perfectly. However, put my server application onto the server and my JSON gets messed up.

Here is the error that I am getting:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: Q. Path '', line 0, position 0.

If it's any sort of a hint, my server application is running on an Amazon EC2 Instance.

What's up?

Comment: Have you checked to see what's in the buffer after it's read? Is it a valid JSON object?

Comment: Well, the thing is... if I copy the project across to the server and then run the application, the error mentioned above is encountered. As soon as I compile the project on the server (rather than compiling on the client and copying the deploy to the server), it works fine! So to answer your question: yes, but I can on only check it on the client as doing so on the server would require a compile on the server, which resolves the issue! Weird.

Comment: Take a look at [TCP client\server - client doesn't always read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652791/tcp-client-server-client-doesnt-always-read).

Comment: You might also have a BOM in your byte array, which `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` will not remove.  To process the BOM correctly, using `StreamReader`, i.e. `string json;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytes))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();`.