# TCPClient Read Write with no response

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I am having an issue with read writes using a TCPClient.  i am able to connect to the server and I get the servers first response which is an authentication message. I then write to the server the required response, however, I am not getting a response back from the server.  The question is, am i doing something wrong where I am blocking that response from being read.

```
static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var messages = MessageSeed();

        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            // Create a TcpClient.
            // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
            // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
            // combination.
            Int32 port = xxxx;
            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse( "xx.xx.xx.xxx" );
            IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint( address, port );
            using( client = new TcpClient() )
            {
                client.Connect( server );

                using( stream = client.GetStream() )
                {
                    // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                    Byte[] data = new Byte[ 256 ];

                    // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                    String responseData = String.Empty;

                    // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                    Int32 bytes = stream.Read( data, 0, data.Length );
                    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString( data, 0, bytes );
                    Console.WriteLine( "Received: {0}", responseData );

                    JTimeMessage firstResposne = new JTimeMessage( responseData );

                    if( firstResposne.MessageIdentifier == "AuthChallenge" )
                    {
                        //Server connection is correct. Need to authenticate
                        string challengString = firstResposne.KVPs[ "ChallengeString" ].ToString();
                        string APIKey = "SomeAPIKey";
                        string sharedSecret = "SomeSharedSecret";
                        string challengeResponseSecrete = CreateChallengeResponse( challengString, sharedSecret );

                        Dictionary<string, string> responseKVPs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        responseKVPs.Add( "APIKey", APIKey );
                        responseKVPs.Add( "ResponseString", challengeResponseSecrete );

                        string responseJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( responseKVPs );

                        string challengeResponse = $"DATA ChallengeResponse {responseJSON}";

                        // Translate the message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                        data = new Byte[ 256 ];
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( challengeResponse );

                        if( stream.CanWrite )
                            Console.Write( "writeable" );

                        // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                        stream.Write( data, 0, data.Length );

                        Console.WriteLine( "Sent: {0}", challengeResponse );

                        // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                        data = new Byte[ 256 ];

                        // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                        responseData = String.Empty;

                        // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.                            
                        Int32 authResultBytes = stream.Read( data, 0, data.Length );
                        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString( data, 0, authResultBytes );
                        Console.WriteLine( "Received: {0}", responseData );
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch( ArgumentNullException e )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "ArgumentNullException: {0}", e );
        }
        catch( SocketException e )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "SocketException: {0}", e );
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
```

Comment: When debugging such issues, it is not enough to show one side. You'll always have to look at both ends of the "tube". I.e.: Does the server _send_ something you could actually read? Does it receive what you write?

Comment: From the first .Read i do receive a response.  After I .Write the .Read does not get anything (i believe).  The server is supposed to be sending back a message if the authentication passed or failed.   Unfortunately i do not have access to the server to verify my .Write has  reached the server.  My assumption is that I am reading the response improperly

Comment: Then you need a test-server. Otherwise it will always be like trying to hit the pinata. Alternatively you can check your network traffic using for example wireshark or the like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCP client\server - client doesn't always read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652791/tcp-client-server-client-doesnt-always-read)